# Stripe ios pod install does not contain file as same as Github stripe project

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment

I wanted to implement standard ui of stripe but the stripe installed through pod does not contain methods to call the shipping view controller.It does not contain the STPShippingMethodsViewController which is used to show standard ui in stripe.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pod repo update
```

and install the lastest stripe use

```
pod 'Stripe'
```

in your `Podfile`